# mySql is not working with django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm stuck to set mysql with django! 
I have python 2.7 and django installed, i have `python-mysql` installed and i have mysql installed with xampp. follow my string connection:

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'mysql',
    'NAME': 'teste',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '',
}
```

When i put 'django.db.backends.mysql' on engine i can run server but when i use 'syncdb' i get an error 'cant connect on mysql'.
When i put just 'mysql' on engine i get an error 'mysql module not found' or something like that.

Django is not connecting with mySql, what am i missing??

i can connect to database on navicat with user root and no password soh i think that was to work on django too. Mysql is installed on c:\xampp\mysql and is running fine.

Comment: can you connect to mysql using the credentials `root` and no password?

Comment: is the mysql process running?

Comment: have you tried installing python-mysqldb  
try with that that might be working and make sure that  

you create a mysql user and grant it all pernissions  

mysql>CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';  
mysql>GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost';

Comment: Try connecting with mysql in terminal using `mysql -u root -p`. If this with works fine, post your mysql password here.

Comment: @arulmr I hope you are not asking someone to write down a password on SO?

Comment: @n3storm The mysql password needs to be specified in django database settings and only then it will connect with the database. But the OP didn't specify any password in the question. I asked it to make sure that he can connect with mysql without using a password.

Comment: I supposed that (that's why I did not flag your comment), but it was confusing so I wanted to make it clear to the OP.

Comment: i can connect to database on navicat with user root and no password soh i think that was to work on django too. Mysql is installed on c:\xampp\mysql and is running fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your MySQL is not working in xampp then first of all close apache. Then open your xampp folder. Then click on the MySQL folder. [Click to see the folder image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7I75.png) Then copy all files into a backup folder then rename the folder to data_old and create a new file named data and paste the backup folder files to the data folder. Then copy your databases folders and ibdata1 file from your data_old folder. then paste it into the data folder. Then open your xampp and start apache and then MySQL. You see MySQL is working.
[Click to see the image that xampp is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcMK2.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).